# How to update website inside Docker? (Locally)

Tags: docker

I use Docker windows locally. I run these codes on Docker and have a running website using Docker.

docker build . -t weblearn

docker run --name weblearn -p 5003:5003 weblearn

It took lots of time to download requirements and install them for the environment.

Then the website is available on the below address:
http://localhost:5003/weblearn

Now I would like to develop the website and make changes to the index.html inside my website. I have a folder named weblearn that contains weblearn website. I changed the index.html file inside this folder but nothing happened to the running website by Docker.
If I delete the image like this:
docker rm weblearn

and then run the following codes again:

docker build . -t weblearn

ocker run --name weblearn -p 5003:5003 weblearn

I see the changes! But as I said it takes lots of time and it is not wise to spend a lot of time for deleting and rebuilding for only small change in website codes.

Is there anything that I can do to somehow update the codes and see the changes through Docker as soon as I change the codes in my editor?

Please ask me if you have question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a volume mount. You can bind the folder you are working with the working directory inside the docker image.
For example

```
docker run --name weblearn  --mount source=your_local_working_dir,target=/app -p 5003:5003 weblearn
```

look at your `dockerfile` to find out your working directory. the source will be the directory you are working on and the target will be the `WORKDIR` inside the container.

After that you change any file in your host machine AKA windows machine docker container will automatically pick up the changes.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the same page after editing files. Is there something I missed?

Comment: could you please share your `Dockerfile` here, also share your directory structure